# Can we upload folder with files in Azure Blob storage like file share?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I need a suggestion on Azure Blob storage. We are using Azure blob storage heavily for various files and now we have a need to categorize these files and stored in folder structure based on certain category. so need to stored same way that we use Azure File share.

Example - Azure Storage Account  A - Container A - Folder1 - File1,File4,File9
Example - Azure Storage Account  A - Container A - Folder2 - File11,File7,File10
Example - Azure Storage Account  A - Container A - Folder3 - File21,File8,File2

We dont want to move to file share as this will require huge efforts, various changes and Azure File share is expensive as well.

Second question is how many blob containers i can create in single storage, is there any limitations?

Please suggest...

Comment: The Blob storage doesn't have directory concept. You can use Azure data lake storage Gen2 for `hierachical namespace` which provides directory support.

Comment: In a storage account, there is no limit for the number of containers, blobs, files. Refer [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/scalability-targets-standard-account)

Comment: Thanks Anand for proposing ADLS Gen2

Answer (score 1):

For folder or directory support, you can use the Azure Data Lake storage Gen2, `hierarchical namespace` feature.

There is *no upper limit* for the number of containers or blobs in a single Storage account.